# Passing Function using Lambda - why does it think the input is Object?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

I have a method:

```
public void foo(Function<InputClass, OutputClass> function){
//...
```

I am trying to pass in a method from another class

```
public class Util{
  public static OutputClass process(InputClass input){
  //...
  }
}
```

so I'm trying to do this:

```
foo(Util::process);
```

However, doing so gives me an error that's like:

```
method process in class Util cannot be applied to given types
        required: InputClass
        found:    java.lang.Object
        reason: argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to InputClass [compiler.err.cant.apply.symbol]
```

That being said, I can do this:

```
Function<InputClass,OutputClass> func = Util::process; 
foo(func);
```

So why does it infer that my input argument is Object instead of InputClass when I give the function directly to foo?

Comment: Is the class that defines `foo` generic?  If so, does it define type parameters `InputClass` and `OutputClass`?  Please supply a [mre].

Comment: We definitely need to see the definition -- not the whole thing, but at least the generics -- of the class that `foo` is in.